# Eigen log and exp functions type casting error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, eigen, point-cloud-library

I am working with Eigen in order to obtain the exponential and the logarithm of a matrix. I do not understand why the following code gives me a compilation error. The code is:

```
Eigen::Matrix4d speedT = Eigen::Matrix4d::Identity();
//some other operations with speedT
Eigen::Matrix4d v = speedT.log();
```

The error is:
Error   17  error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const Eigen::MatrixExponentialReturnValue' to 'Eigen::Matrix4d'

Error   16  error C2027: use of undefined type 'Eigen::MatrixExponentialReturnValue'

For the exponential function (exp) the same issue appears. I have tried different variations of it also make a type cast (Eigen::Matrix4d) speedT.log(); however the result was the same...
The version of eigen is  Eigen 3.2.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this error shows up if you forget to

```
#include <unsupported/Eigen/MatrixFunctions>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! In the mean time I also found that I would have to include the two headers #include <Eigen/LU> and
#include <unsupported/Eigen/MatrixFunctions>. Even so thank you very much!